# TableLayout heightPercentage: percentage of what?

Tags: codenameone, tablelayout

I need to create a `Container` with a layout of two rows, the second one twice the height of the first, and put the container in the south position of a `BorderLayout`. I tried to do this using a `TableLayout` with two rows and one column, setting the height percentages to 33 and 67, respectively. However the `TableLayout` filled the entire screen, not just the "South" area. The [javadocs](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/table/TableLayout.Constraint.html#setHeightPercentage-int-) indicate that the height percentage refers to the "parent", which I assumed would be the container with the `TableLayout`. But, apparently, the parent in question will be the display.

My next attempt was to create a TableLayout with three rows and one column, giving the lower content a vertical span of 2. But the bottom rows just disappeared.

Is there a solution I overlooked?

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate stages in layout, requesting the preferred size and dealing with assigned size.

During the request stage we don't have the final size of everything so this is "guesstimated" (which amazingly my spell checker didn't flag?).

As we do the layout we already have an assigned size based on that preferred size and then the percentage is calculated based on that assigned size.

If you place a table layout container in the center of a border layout it will get all available space and so the preferred size aspect of the calculation phase will become meaningless and then percentage will be of the space allocated to the component which is "all available space". Naturally scrolling brings this into a completely different dimension.